# How can I automatically restart chromium if it crashes?

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, chromium

I'm using chromium-browser in kiosk mode as a display, but from time to time it might crash.
I'd like to be able to kill / re-start the browser if that happens, but I'm unable to check chrome's status.

Does anyone know how to check if chromium has crashed, or configure chrome to shutdown if it crashes?

`Chromium 28.0.1500.52 Ubuntu 12.04`

Comment: http://mmonit.com/monit/

Answer (score 2):

Put the following code in a file, name it whatever you like (foo):

```
#!/bin/sh
while :        # run forever
do
   chromium-browser
done
```

Then execute:

```
chmod +x foo
```

to make the file named foo executable.

When your kiosk starts, invoke the program foo (the file you just created).

The script runs the chrome browser in a "do this forever" loop. If the browser ever dies (for whatever reason), the script will restart it.

Comment: I've already got something similar (but it's in my minutely cron, and wrapped in a a `ps ax | grep chromium`). The problem is that when a page crashes, chrome doesn't shut down, so this solution doesn't catch that scenario..

Comment: Got here through google and just wanted to say thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.