# Chrome Restart Script On Crash Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, firefox, crash

So a service I am using will no longer be allowing Firefox as a default browser on Ubuntu anymore.

Currently I have the following script which will check if Firefox has crashed/closed and it will restart the instance to my desired URL. (Modified for chrome).

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNTER=0
while true
do
if [ ! `pgrep google-chrome-bin` ] ; then
echo -e '\nOh no, Google Chrome is not running! Restarting it now! \n\n'
echo Google Chrome has been restarted $COUNTER times
let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
google-chrome --private URLHERE
fi
sleep 30
done
```

The issue is that Chrome doesn't crash like Firefox. Instead you get the "Aw snap!" error message.

I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17938587/5188217

But when I execute that, it will open numerous new tabs.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to write an auto-restart script for chrome. Currently the one I am using does not detect the "Aw snap!" crash so it doesn't do anything.